# cURL error 35 while installing plugin on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I keep getting this error when installing WordPress plugins, what could be wrong?

> Installation failed: Download failed. cURL error 35: error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Seems your SSL verifier needs to turn off. Use the following code.

```
function skip_ssl_verify($ssl_verify) {
    return false;
}
add_filter('https_ssl_verify', 'skip_ssl_verify');
add_filter('https_local_ssl_verify', 'skip_ssl_verify');
```

Add the code to functions.php file.